# Maven site plugin not getting downloaded by intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, maven-site-plugin

I am building a spring project in Intellij community edition using maven.
I can see the maven-site-plugin folder created in my local m2 repository:

```
C:\Users\user_name\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-site-plugin
```

Inside, i see only one file named **maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom.lastUpdated** with the below content:

```
#NOTE: This is a Maven Resolver internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Thu Oct 28 17:03:21 IST 2021
@default-central-https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1635420801486
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins\:maven-site-plugin\:pom\:3.3 from/to central (https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)\: Transfer failed for https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
```

I took a fresh clone of the repo, did a clean build, also tried Intellij's cache invalidate and restart but to no avail..

Comment: Do you use any antivirus software or firewall/proxy? Could you please try to build it from command line outside IDE?

Comment: It worked after i deleted the empty folder and ran a maven clean install. Not sure why that happen in the first place though..